# Trignometric inequalities.

Tags: limits, trigonometry

I was working through a question on limits where the author suggested the inequality:

$ |\sin(x)| \leq x $ in some deleted neighbourhood around 0,

I'm kind of unsure if the inequality is correct because in a neighbourhood around 0 we would have x<0, but $|\sin(x)| > 0 $ for all x in any neighbourhood around 0. Am i missing anything?

Edit:
1.) removed the line "which leads to:
$-x \leq \sin x \leq x $  "

Comment: Are you referring to $|\sin{x}|$ or $\sin{x}$?

Comment: @Dstarred |sin x|

Comment: Consider the Taylor series of $\sin (x)$ which is an alternating series, thus clearly $x$ when $ 0 \leq x \leq 1$

Comment: Firstly, why is the tag "limits-without-lhopital" required here? Secondly, do you assume dual limit or single, as you stated $x < 0, \space (x \to 0^-?)$, but you also state any $x$ **around** $0$.

Comment: @benhuni but in a neighbourhood around 0, there will be values where x < 0.

Comment: @Dstarred a deleted neighbourhood around zero would contain - ve values of x.

Comment: @grey I agree but clearly, for negative values of x, this is not true because of the modulus

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right, when $x<0$ the inequality $|\sin x| \le x$ is obviously false, and likewise for $-x \le \sin x \le x$.

(But $|\sin x| \le |x|$ is true for all real $x$.)